# Difference of using FormData and Json Array based Ajax Posting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I was wondering what exactly is the difference or if any adabathage gained from passing **POST** data using **FormData in AJAX** / Jquery and Normal Json array construction.

I used FormData and I see the following in post for every variable sent it has a content type and other information, is that really necessary ?
Example FormDATA posting:

```
                        var form_data = new FormData();                  
                        form_data.append("file", file_data);
                        form_data.append("fname",fname), 
==>on submit data: form_data, 



e08868d6629941cdc8549f7e4b8fbe92
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryAGXugLSkGAWzo2j7
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="imagefile[]"; filename="car2.jpg"
    Content-Type: image/jpeg

    ------WebKitFormBoundaryAGXugLSkGAWzo2j7
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fname"
```

Json

```
data: {fname:"thisisfname"},
```

Comment: difference between FormData in AJAX and Normal Json array construction??